# Can I have an instance variable? (Answer at bottom of my post)

Tags: python, django

In typical Python classes, I can have an instance variable, like so:

```
class MyClass():
    def __init__(self):
        self.myvar = ""
```

Is there a way to do this with Django management commands?

```
class Command(BaseCommand):
    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        # I want to have a class variable here
```

Piggybacking off of @shredding's answer below, this is how you'd override the `__init__` properly, according to the Django documentation [found here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/custom-management-commands/#methods):

```
class Command(BaseCommand):
    def __init__(self, stdout=None, stderr=None, no_color=False):
        super(Command, self).__init__(stdout, stderr, no_color)
            self.myvar = ""
```

Comment: What does this have to do with a management command?.. what are you trying to do?..

Comment: BTW: `myvar` is an instance variable, not a class variable.

Comment: @KlausD. Shoot, you're right.  I don't know what I was thinking.  Thanks for correcting me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course, just overwrite the init method:

```
class YourCommand(BaseCommand)
    def __init__(self, stdout=None, stderr=None, no_color=False):
        super().__init__(stdout, stderr, no_color)
        self.your_var = ''

    def handle(self, *args, **kwargs):
        ... logic goes here ...
```

BaseCommand is just a Plain old Python Object.

Comment: I should have specified this in my question.  If I'm on Python 2.7, should I be passing something to super().__init__()?  If I don't, I get a `TypeError: super() takes at least 1 argument (0 given)` error.

Comment: as always you have two options... 1) look at the source of the super-class and see what args it takes and make sure your `__init__` takes them as well and passes via `super()`  or 2) just take `__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)` and pass the `*args, **kwargs` to super

Comment: As a side note, you can create instance vars wherever you want, it must not necessarily need to be in the `__init__` method. After all they are simply attached to the instance. However, this is considered bad practise (because it's not clear if the var is already set or not if you add it to different method).